# (1/1) FatalErrorException Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in Laravel. As I am learning it for the very first time, I am facing a lot more problems in every tutorial.

Recently I am facing
**(1/1) FatalErrorException

Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider'                                         not found in ProviderRepository.php line 208**

problem. I am Searching a lot, Reading A lot but could not find a way to solve. As for My Project got Stuck in that state.

That's my ProviderRopository.php line 208.

```
public function createProvider($provider)
{
    return new $provider($this->app);

}
```

Hope you will help me.

Comment: I think you forgot to update your composer file `composer require laravelcollective/html` !!

Comment: I did `composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0"` I don't know is it do update or not. Hope you would help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alhumdulillah

It worked.

First I have tried all of those three commands one after another.

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

then to check:

in every time when the problem was on, if i command

`$ php artisan --version`

it usually shows that error to me,

`'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found in C:\xa`
`mpp\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepo`
`sitory.php on line 208`

`In ProviderRepository.php line 208:`

`Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found`

that means, I would not able to see my laravel version.

But after doing those aforesaid commands, I restarted codes by commenting, saving and deleting comment, I am now able to watch my laravel version.

`$ php artisan --version`

`Laravel Framework 5.4.36`

So, now I am thinking, My problem has solved.

Comment: Alhumdulillah. Yes, it is solved and I am going further by the Grace of Allah.